# Why getAffineTransform return zero Matrix

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV to do some image processing job. I want to transform a image with affine method. This is my code:

```
Point2f srcTri[3];
Point2f dstTri[3];

srcTri[0] = Point2f( 0.0, 1.0 );
srcTri[1] = Point2f( 50.0, 1.0);
srcTri[2] = Point2f( 10.0, 1.0);

dstTri[0] = Point2f( 1.0, 1.0);
dstTri[1] = Point2f( 5.0, 50.0 );
dstTri[2] = Point2f( 110.0, 200.0 );

Mat warpMat = getAffineTransform( srcTri, dstTri );
cout << warpMat << endl;
```

But the print result is a zero Matrix. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the points in the source have the same `y` coordinates and therefore the source triangle is not really a triangle but a line.

You are trying to solve a singular problem. Any affine transformation of a line is a line (you cannot "inflate" a line in an area).